# API Gateway wrapping response in XML tags

Tags: json, xml, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Without pasting the whole Terraform code, maybe someone recognizes this problem:

When I set up a Lambda function on AWS and couple it to the API gateway, my json responses get wrapped into XML tags.

Lambda function:

```
def handler(event, __):
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        'body': json.dumps({"foo": "bar"})
     }
```

But when I send a HTTP request, I get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message>
    {
    "foo": "bar"
}
</message>
```

Also, when I test the resource, the tags are not yet there. I can find nothing about `<message>` in the documentation, and I swear I never use these XML tags.

Anyone recognizes these tags? And knows how to remove them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What integration type are you using in API Gateway? Is there a custom response mapping being applied in API Gateway?

Comment: AWS_PROXY integration type. The tags occur both with response mapping on and off.